# Problem with IE8 on ubuntu

Tags: playonlinux, ie

While working with IE8 on Ubuntu I am facing some problems.

1. I'm not able to open a new tab; if I do so, then an message comes up: "playonlinux seems to have crashed."
2. I'm not able to work on IE8 for a long time; the same message comes and IE8 goes out.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your question is a bit unclear. IE8 (which I assume is Internet Explorer) isn't a native Linux application. Could you elaborate on how you installed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (from the error message) you installed IE8 through PlayOnLinux, it's important to note that IE8 "[isn't fully functional (for using it on a daily basis) at the moment](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-531-Internet_Explorer_8.html)," according to the PlayOnLinux website.  There seem to be quite a few people running into problems with IE8 crashing when opening tabs or even when loading pages.

If you need IE8 to do browser testing (e.g. for web development), I'd strongly recommend using a Windows virtual machine instead. [modern.ie](http://modern.ie) is an official Microsoft website that [provides virtual machine images](https://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) that should let you run IE8 in Windows 7 using VirtualBox on Ubuntu.

If you use [Seamless Mode](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#seamlesswindows), you'll be able to use IE8 side-by-side with Ubuntu applications, and it won't even feel like a virtual machine (but the result will be a much more stable and accurate implementation of IE8).

Comment: OK I understand the complexity of IE8, but I do not want to use IE8 on windows, but only on Ubuntu,how could it is possible.

Comment: @ManishKumar could I ask why? IE8 wasn't mean to run with Wine, so it will never run as well as it does in Windows, which you can easily do for free, without ever leaving Ubuntu. If you use VirtualBox in seamless mode, it won't look any different than running it through PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Thanks..........but still I will try to use IE8 with wine any how,this is tough but i'll try.

Comment: @ManishKumar I have run into a situation where a website strongly requires that I access it via Internet Explorer. My environment is Ubuntu, I installed IE8 via PlayOnLinux but IE8 seems to fail to access the internet. Did you have any luck  running IE8 via wine? How did you do it? Looking forward to your response.